# Builder and Abstract Factory pattern together

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

How can we use builder and abstract factory pattern together?

Builder pattern is used to instantiate complex objects and abstract factory pattern is used to create group of similar object without requiring the exact classes.

If we want to create complex objects(Builder Pattern) without knowing the exact classes(Abstract factory pattern), then how it is possible ?

Comment: Builder pattern orchestrates the building of a thing. Imagine a caterer directing the building of a feast. "BuildPizza", "BuildCake", etc. Internally a `Builder.BuildPart()` could very well use an abstract factory to build a pizza. I think of patterns as organic molecules - you can string them together just about any which way to make anything.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you choose what to build in the factory, and you then use a builder to build it:

```
public class FooFactory {

    public Foo create(String name, String reference) {
        if (reference.startsWith("fake")) {
            return FakeFoo.builder().withName(name).withReference(reference).build();
        }
        else {
            return RealFoo.builder().withName(name).withReference(reference).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have lost the benefits of builder ,what if you need to pass more attributes to the builder ? you need to change the factory , I believe such  a problem can be explained as you have an class too many attributes (Builder) and many sub classes to be created (factory).